# Migrating to Android Studio. Error unable to class org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instatntiator

Tags: android, eclipse

I am very new to Android development.  I first learned in Eclipse environment.   I was trying to import a project from Eclipse to Android Studio. I followed the instructions on the Android developer site, but I encountered this error:

```
Error: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instantiator'.
```

> This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
>
> File a bug
>
> Show log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem was solved. i tried a different approach in migrating my project to the android studio. i did not follow the steps in the android developer's site. i imported it without generating gradle from eclipse. i made a copy of my project from eclipse and imported it using the import project in android studio it automatically generated its own gradle and included the libraries i used in eclipse. it took a while but it worked.